# how to convert string like "11aacc" to hex value []byte("\x11\xaa\cc") in golang

Tags: go

i want to use UDP to send packet with content like 0x11AACC, "11AACC" is fetched from database, so it's string.

I don't know how to change it to hex value 11AACC, if I use []byte("11AACC")to convert it, it'll change to 6 bytes content.

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `DecodeString` from `encoding/hex` package to convert your hex string to []byte.

example: https://play.golang.org/p/t200M1LqJQ3

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    s := "11AACC"
    h, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

Link to DecodeString: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString